# Looking to create a word document from code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, docx, receipt

I have this code:

```
import random
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches 
title = "seans store"
"""
Declare the two dictionaries with name stock and prices
"""
stock = {
    "banana": 60,
    "apple": 150,
    "orange": 120,
    "pear": 150,
    "tomatoes": 120,
    "yoghurt": 100
}

prices = {
    "yoghurt": 1,
    "banana": 2,
    "apple": 1,
    "orange": .5,
    "pear": 1.5,
    "tomatoes": 1.1
}
"""
Declare the items within the customers shopping cart
"""
shopping_cart = [("pear",1), ("orange", 1), ("apple",2), ("tomatoes",2), ("yoghurt",0)]
for i in shopping_cart:
    if stock[i[0]] - i[1] < 0:
        shopping_cart.pop(shopping_cart.index(i))
    else:
        stock[i[0]] -= i[1]
print(f"Thank you for shopping @ {title.title()}")
for x in range(1):
    Order_number = random.randint(100,999)
total_items = sum([i[1] for i in shopping_cart])
print(f"Your Order number is: {Order_number}")
print(f"Total items bought: {total_items}")
print("----------------")
print("     Bill")
print("----------------")
for i in shopping_cart:
    print(f"{i[0]} x{i[1]} @  £{prices[i[0]]}")
total = (sum([prices[i[0]] * i[1]  for i in shopping_cart]))
total_after_tax = total + (total*0.2)
tax_total = total_after_tax - total
print("----------------")
print("VAT @: £{:.2f}".format(tax_total))
print("----------------")
print("Total is £{:.2f}".format(total_after_tax))
"""Reciept creation"""
document = Document()
document.add_heading(f'Reciept for {title.title()}', 0)
p = document.add_paragraph('Items Ordered: ')

document.save("Reciept.docx")
```

and I want to create a document from this that lists the items the customer has ordered and their prices as a receipt. I am hoping to create this so I can automate receipt creation processes in the future. I am also curious if it is possible to get the code to automatically print or open the word document software when the code is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly - you intend to output the print statements to the word document. The only way you can do that is by adding an `.add_paragraph()` method via the `docx` library.

A good example from the [documentaiton](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
p.add_run(' and some ')
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

document.add_heading('Heading, level 1', level=1)
document.add_paragraph('Intense quote', style='Intense Quote')

document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in unordered list', style='List Bullet'
)
document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in ordered list', style='List Number'
)

document.add_picture('monty-truth.png', width=Inches(1.25))

document.add_page_break()

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Once you save the file, you can open it by simply opening the file in the standard way using the `os` module. This will default to whatever application you have set to open files of type `.docx` type.

```
import os
os.startfile('C:\\Path\\To\\demo.docx')
```

Comment: yes but as you can see from the code I want to send the item name, their prices, and the amount bought to the word document which is proving difficult as I cant apply a variable name to a for loop and then call it to apply it to the word document

Comment: Can you expand what you mean here ` which is proving difficult as I cant apply a variable name to a for loop and then call it to apply it to the word document` - maybe add it to the question to elucidate things better